# Sitecore 7:Validate Date fields using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Can we validate two Date fields in sitecore content editor using Javascript?

Here I have a Start Date and a End Date field I need to tell the user that End Date Should always be greater than Start Date.So can I do this using a Javascript and not allow them to save till it is corrected.

Please let me know if this is possible instead of using Save UI or Save pipeline or Validators(I was not able to do with Validators as I was not getting pre saved values with it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use validators (which is really the right tool for the job), your best alternative option is to create your own custom field. It's a fair amount of work, but it will allow you to control everything about the field, when it gets saved to the database and similar.

Information here: http://gettingtoknowsitecore.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/custom-fields-part-1.html

You would need a custom field that allowed the user to enter both Start and End dates, and not allowing save if validation fails.

Comment: I was not able to use validators as it was not giving me presaved values with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validation rules and code your validation logic in C#. Also, be sure to have the result parameter of the validator set to `Result=FatalError`.

Comment: I was not able to use validators as it was not giving me  presaved values with it.

Comment: What do yoh mean by "not giving you presaved values?"

Comment: By presaved value i mean that say whenever u change start date from 5 june to 6 june.I always get 5 june and not the 6 june in validator code behin.

Comment: Also I Had posted a question on this as well @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539638/sitecore7-validate-presaved-date-field but did not get any response..:(

Comment: You can also try to do this using a Save event handler, if all else fails